# Get DOM content after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am testing a view WYSIWYG editors (ckeditor, sceditor, wysibb). They work all same. A textarea with a ID is the anchor and holds the entire dom-object.

**Example in the source:**

```
<textarea id="example"></texarea>
```

**Becomes in DOM to:**

```
<textarea id="example" style="display:none"></texarea>

<div id="editor">
 <head>
 </head>
  <body>
     Content of the Editor
  </body>
</div>
```

**Question:**

How is it possible to write something inside of the body, when the body is not in the source?

The reason is, I have a to sync everything from the textarea (example ID) to the editor body, when something is added to the textarea.

I tried:

```
$("#example, #editor.body").on("change keyup", function(){
$("textarea").not($(this)).val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: maybe try `$(document).on("change keyup","textarea", function(){`

Comment: CKeditor has inbuilt functionality to update the body `CKEDITOR.instances[**fieldname**].setData(**your data**)`

Comment: I have CKEDITOR installed at the moment. CK set the textarea to display:none and visibility:hidden. When something is added via javascript to the textarea, how is it possible to add this to the body? (sync)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
     Your stuff
});
```

This loads callback only after the whole page has finished loading.